# how to get a private variable in c++

Tags: c++

```
template<typename Type> class ListNode{
private:
    Type nodeData;
    ListNode *nextNode;

    friend class SingleList<Type>;
    ListNode():nextNode(NULL){} 
    ListNode(const Type item,ListNode<Type> *next=NULL):nodeData(item),nextNode(next){} 
    ~ListNode(){
        nextNode=NULL;
    }

public:
    Type GetData();
    friend ostream& operator<< <Type>(ostream& ,ListNode<Type>&);    
};


template<typename Type> Type ListNode<Type>::GetData(){
    return this->nodeData;
}
//here, compiler said 'nodeData is a private member of ListNode<int>'
```

The compiler said 'nodeData is a private member of ListNode'

how can I get a private variable?

or any get/set functions in c++ like Java?

Comment: Does "here" mean on the GetData function at, return this->nodeData; or in the whitespace after the closing brace?

Comment: @doctorlove here, means the GetData function at, return this->nodeData

Comment: what if you move the definition of GetData inside the template? i.e.  Type GetData() { return nodeData; };

Comment: It compiles on my machine, if I comment out the friend class line, since I have no idea what a SingleList is. Can you post the *exact* code that doesn't compile?

Comment: Oh, Sorry. I made another mistake. Same other places call here and make the compiler to fail. "return nodeData" or "return this-->nodeData" are both right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use a get/set methods to get data.

To pass the actual object you should use a pointer or a reference.

To pass a copy just pass by value.

This is the main difference between Java and C++ when it comes to passing objects.

Your getdata method is only returning a copy of nodeData, which depending you might want to do or not. If its a large object it should be done by reference, otherwise a copy is alright.

Edit:
as for it saying that it is a private variable, I'm not sure why it is doing that. I copied your code and ran it myself with no compiler error.